# Junit parameterization setting constant in the test class

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to run a parameterized junit test where parameter must be constant in the test, so I am using Reflection to set that parameter. However it is not quite working. In the example below, it always prints `Testing with: param-1`. How can I solve this issue? Surprisingly, I get correct values for PARAM_NAME (param-1, param-2, param-2) in debugger for different run instances but its printed always as "param-1" at console and its also used in tests as "param-1". This can be partly explained by the fact that an annotation is evaluated at compile time so the value in annotation can't be changed during run time?

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class SomeTest {

private final String PARAM_NAME = "param-1";

public SomeTest(String someParam){
    org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.setField(this, "PARAM_NAME", someParam);
}

@Parameterized.Parameters
public static Collection parameters() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
            { "param-1" },
            { "param-2" },
            { "param-3" }
    });
}

@Test
@ExternalAnnotation(PARAM_NAME) //needs constant in annotation
public void testSomething() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Testing with: "+PARAM_NAME); //always prints param-1
    //some tests
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotation values are cached by the JVM, and there's no way you can change that at runtime. The only possible way I can think of that you can achieve what you are trying to do is to generate your test class programmatically through source code generation (template based, or using a library like [JCodeModel](https://github.com/phax/jcodemodel)). If you do that in a lifecycle phase before test compilation (assuming you are using a build system like Maven or Gradle), then you you should be up and running relatively easily.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do it by changing annotation value at run time:

```
public static void changeAnnotationValue(Annotation annotation, String key, Object newValue) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Object handler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(annotation);
    Field f = handler.getClass().getDeclaredField("memberValues");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Map<String, Object> memberValues = (Map<String, Object>) f.get(handler);
    memberValues.put(key,newValue);
}
```

I am calling this method in following way:

```
public SomeTest(String someParam){ changeAnnotationValue(SomeTest.class.getMethod("testSomething").getAnnotation(ExternalAnnotation.class), "value", someParam);}
```

Although its totally not advisable to do in main code, There can be side effects. I am just doing it in a test class.